# QGIS no touch zoom and pan

Tags: qgis, zoom, pan, linux-mint

QGIS 2.12.1 under Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon: I have no touch zoom and pan icon.  Touch screen works for panning and other stuff but I cannot pinch to zoom.

Any fix?

Comment: Is your Navigation Toolbar turned off or hidden?  https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/qgis_gui.html

Comment: On.  Have now found touchegg and installed.  Pinching now works (sort of) but icon still missing.  I think that's as good as it gets, thanks!

Comment: Graham where you found the  touchegg?

Comment: In the LM/Ubuntu repo.